# Post Data to a URL actionscript

Tags: forms, flash, post, actionscript, adobe

I am having real trouble here. I am very new at Flash and have created a form that i then need to post the data to a URL. I have no clue how to do this and all i find online is information that include PHP.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

which actionscript version are you using?

for actionscript2 you need to use LoadVars (sendAndLoad example here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001161.html)

for actionscript3 you need to use URLRequest and URLLoader (example here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary)

the actionscript3 reference is very horribly written and unreadable though, so you might want to check this post out http://labs.grupow.com/blog/2008/11/06/sending-variables-in-as3-aka-sendandload-in-as2